# How can I pass object parameters to the onclick function in backtick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying run the onclick function in backticks, when i clicked.

backticks :

```
   socket.onmessage = function(event){
   console.log(event.data);
   const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    data.map((person)=>{
        console.log(person)
       $("#unknown-persons").append(`
       <div class="media p-l-5">
       <div class="pull-left">
           <img width="40" src="${person.image}" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="media-body">
           <small class="text-muted">${new Date(parseInt(person.time))}</small><br/>
           <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-unknown-person" onclick="labelingToUser(person)">${person.name} ${person.lastname}</a>
       </div>
   </div> 
   `)

    })
   }
```

onclick function:

```
function labelingToUser(){}
```

But i can not pass  the person object as parameter to my onclik function. How can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Person is not global object, so its not accessible to append function.

Try this

```
var personglobal;
socket.onmessage = function(event){
   console.log(event.data);
   const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    data.map((person)=>{
personglobal = person;
        console.log(person)
       $("#unknown-persons").append(`
       <div class="media p-l-5">
       <div class="pull-left">
           <img width="40" src="${person.image}" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="media-body">
           <small class="text-muted">${new Date(parseInt(person.time))}</small><br/>
           <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-unknown-person" onclick="labelingToUser(personglobal)">${person.name} ${person.lastname}</a>
       </div>
   </div> 
   `)

    })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `JSON.stringify(person`) method to convert the object ot json string
then pass it to the function calling as following:

```
  socket.onmessage = function(event){
   console.log(event.data);
   const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    data.map((person)=>{
        console.log(person)
       $("#unknown-persons").append(`
       <div class="media p-l-5">
       <div class="pull-left">
           <img width="40" src="${person.image}" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="media-body">
           <small class="text-muted">${new Date(parseInt(person.time))}</small><br/>
           <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-unknown-person" onclick="labelingToUser(${JSON.stringify(person)})">${person.name} ${person.lastname}</a>
       </div>
   </div> 
   `)

    })
   }


function labelingToUser(person){}
```